# In hibernate how to map two foreign keys in one table to one primary key in another table

Tags: hibernate

The ER diagram is as below 
[ER diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aopP.png)

I have created the entities classes as below :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state_flows")
public class StateFlowEntity {

private int id;
private StateMachineEntity stateMachine;
private StateEntity currentState;
private StateEntity nextState;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "current_state", referencedColumnName = "id",
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
public StateEntity getCurrentState() {
return currentState;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "next_state", referencedColumnName = "id",
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
public StateEntity getNextState() {
return nextState;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "machine_id", referencedColumnName = "id",
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
public StateMachineEntity getStateMachine() {
return stateMachine;
}

//setters and getters
```

===================================================================

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "states")
public class StateEntity {

public enum NodeType {
EVENT
};

private int id;
private String name;
private NodeType nodeType;
private String nodeId;
private int ratio;
private int missingRatio;
private String nodeDetail;
private Set<StateFlowEntity> nextStateFlows = new HashSet<StateFlowEntity>();
private Set<StateFlowEntity> currentStateFlows = new HashSet<StateFlowEntity>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "nextState",
    targetEntity = StateEntity.class)
public Set<StateFlowEntity> getNextStateFlows() {
return nextStateFlows;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "currentState",
    targetEntity = StateEntity.class)
public Set<StateFlowEntity> getCurrentStateFlows() {
return currentStateFlows;
}

@Column(name = "node_type", nullable = false,
    columnDefinition = "ENUM('EVENT') default 'EVENT'")
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private NodeType getNodeType() {
return nodeType;
}

//setter and getters
```

======================================================================================

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state_machines")
public class StateMachineEntity {

private int id;
private String name;
private String description;
private int initialState;
private int combinational;
private Set<StateFlowEntity> machineId = new HashSet<StateFlowEntity>();
private Set<InstanceEntity> instances = new HashSet<InstanceEntity>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "stateMachine")
public Set<StateFlowEntity> getMachineId() {
return machineId;
}

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "stateMachine")
public Set<InstanceEntity> getInstances() {
return instances;
}

//setters and getters
```

=============================================================

but its giving me below error:

Error in intializing database connections.
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.test.orm.entity.StateEntity.currentState in com.test.entity.StateEntity.currentStateFlows

I am new to hibernate, where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use targetEntity on the `StateEntity` here?  The collection type `StateEntity` doesn't expose the named attributes for either `nextState` and `currentState`, so you'll likely get this error for both.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Naros mentioned, targetEntity should be "StateFlowEntity.class" or need not be specified at all.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "currentState",
    targetEntity = StateEntity.class)
```

Since you explicitly mentioned "targetEntity = StateEntity.class" in your code, it is looking for "currentState" field in "StateEntity" class. That is the meaning of the error message.

I was able to load these entities with Spring Boot after making these changes.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "nextState",
        targetEntity = StateFlowEntity.class)
private Set<StateFlowEntity> nextStateFlows = new HashSet<StateFlowEntity>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "currentState" )
private Set<StateFlowEntity> currentStateFlows = new HashSet<StateFlowEntity>();
```

Comment: Thanks, removing the targetEntity eliminates the error